# Multiple deployers single Content Delivery database (Broker DB)

Tags: tridion

In the publishing scenario I have, we have multiple deployers pushing content to both file system and database (broker).  Pages and Binaries are put on the file system, everything else in the Broker.  We have one of the deployers putting the content into the database. Is this the recommended best practice?

If the storage configurations in all deployers also put the content into the database, how does Tridion handle this?  Could this cause duplicate entries, locking failures etc?

I'm afraid at the time of writing I don't have access to an environment to test how this would work.

Answer (score 11):

SDL best practice is to have a one-to-one relationship between a deployer and a publication; that means so long as two deployers do not publish the same content (from the same publication) then they will not collide providing, if a file system, there is separation between the deployed sites e.g. www/pub1 & www/pub2.

Your explanation of your scenario needs some additional information to make it complete but it sounds most likely that there are multiple broker databases (albeit hosted on a single database server). This is the most common setup when dealing with multiple file systems on webservers, combined with a single database server.

I personally do not like this set up as I think it would be better to host file system content in a shared location & share single DB. Or better still deploy everything to the database and uses something like DD4T/CWA.

Comment: In this situation, lets assume it's a single publication, which is publishing to multiple deployers, but it's just the one that publishes to the broker.  What advice do you have here?

Comment: If one deployer publishes to the broker only, then you have a SPOF. If the deployer doing the database deployment fails, then deployment for all other deployers will be incomplete. If the organziation does not want to have a different infrastructure to make this more robust, then the best is to have all dpeloyers doing the same thing (file system & database) and have seperate broker databases for each deployer.

Answer (score 6):

I have seen (and even recommended based on customer limitations) similar configurations where you have multiple deployers configured as destinations of a given target.

Only one of the deployers can write to the database for the same transaction, otherwise you'll have concurrency issues. So one deployer writes to the database, while all others write to the file system.

All brokers/web applications are configured to **read** from the database.

This solves the issue of deploying to multiple servers and/or data centers where using a shared file system (preferred approach) is not feasible - be it for cost or any other reason).

In short - not a best practice, but it is known to work.

Answer (score 1):

Julian's and Nuno's approaches cover most of the common scenarios. Indeed a single database is a single point of failure, but in many installations, you are expected to run multiple schemas on the same database server, so you still have a single point of failure even if you have multiple "Broker DBs".

Another alternative to consider is totally independent delivery nodes. This might even mean running a database server on your presentation box. These days it's all virtual anyway so you could run separate small database servers. (Licensing costs would be an important constraint)

Each delivery server has it's own database and file system. Depending on how many you want, you might not want to set up multiple destinations/deployers, so you deploy to one, and use file system replication and database log shipping to mirror the content to the rest.

Of course, you could configure two deployment systems (or three) for redundancy, assuming you can manage all the clustering etc.

OK - to come clean - I've never built one like this, but I'm fairly sure elements of this kind of design will become more common as virtualisation increases, and licensing models which support it. (Maybe we have to wait for Tridion to support an open source database!)